# iframe with blobUrl pdf only printing first page in iPad

Tags: ipad, printing

I am running and iPad printing issue in our reactjs application. We have blob generated from pdfMake package then we are creating a blobUrl from this blob and setting as a src to iframe and printing in iPad but it is printing only first page while my pdf contains 3 pages.

My code snippet is-

```
 pdfMake.createPdf(dataInput).getBlob((blob) => {
    const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const targetElement = document.querySelector("#iframeContainer");
    const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.height = "100%";
    iframe.width = "100%";
    iframe.src = blobURL;
    iframe.id = "printIframe";
    iframe.name = "testiframe";
    targetElement?.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.onload = function () {
      if (iframe && iframe.contentWindow) {
          iframe.contentWindow.focus();
          iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }
    };
  });
```

I am expecting to print all the pages in pdf  file while printing in iPad.